# How to fetch music files from external storage in React Native

Tags: react-native, android-music-player

I am new to react native and creating a music player app that access music from external storage and put them into a list. Can anyone suggest me any library or any way to implement the functionality. I am stuck in how I fetch music files from the external storage. If there is any library or something, please suggest me.

I have also tried 'npm install react-native-get-music-files --save' but it is throwing some error while installation.